# Using the child's static variable in a parent's static method

Tags: python-3.x, static-methods

I am currently trying to abstract/default some behaviour away. All children define some constants differently and I want to reference said variable in their parent class. My attempt looks something like this:

```
class Mother():
    a= True

    @staticmethod
    def something():
        return Mother.a


class Child(Mother):
    a = False


print(Mother.something())
print(Child.something())
```

`Mother.something()` obviously produces `True`, but `Child.something()` should produce `False`.

This doesn't work as I guess in inheritance in Python you don't override the variables but just hides them outside of vision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Child` class, when `something` is called, `Mother.a` is still valid, you're referring to the parent `Mother` class (defined at `Child`s class declaration). Python has another builtin called [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) for your use case:

```py
class Mother():
    a = True

    @classmethod
    def something(cls):
        return cls.a

class Child(Mother):  # Mother.a gets defined here
    a = False

print(Mother.something())  # True
print(Child.something())  # False
```

From the docs:

> Class methods are different than C++ or Java static methods. If you want those, see staticmethod().

`@classmethod`s define `cls` (by convention, the variable doesn't have to be called `cls`) as the first argument, just like instance methods would receive `self` as their first argument. `cls` refers to the class that the method is being called on.

I'd recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg) for a great introduction on best practices for classes and how/where to use all the special decorators/syntax in python.

Since you mentioned abstract classes, you may be interested in the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) module as well.